# Using a `defconst' or `defvar' While the Variable Has a Local Binding Sets the Global Binding?

Tags: variables, lexical-binding, defvar

The *GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual*, [12.5 Defining Global Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Variables.html):

> If you use a `defconst` or `defvar` special form **while the variable has a local binding** (made with `let`, or a function argument), **it sets the local binding** rather than the global binding.

---

But when I tried it in `*scratch*`:

```lisp
(defun f (some-symbol)
  (defconst some-symbol 1412)
  some-symbol)
;; ==> f

(f 0)
;; ==> 0

some-symbol
;; ==> 1412
```

It seems that `(defconst some-symbol 1412)` didn't set the local value of `some-symbol` (so that `(f 0)` evaluates to `0`), instead it made the `some-symbol` at top level evaluate to `1412`.

Do I misunderstand the definitions of ***local binding*** and ***global binding***?

---

### Update

[Another example](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76258/using-a-defconst-or-defvar-while-the-variable-has-a-local-binding-sets-the-g?noredirect=1#comment125996_76258) that seems to work fine for [@dalanicolai](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/26163/):

> Although `defconst` does work as documented when using it with `let`: `(let ((some-symbol 0)) (defconst some-symbol 1412) some-symbol)` returns 1412.

but behaves weirdly in my Emacs:

```lisp
*** Welcome to IELM ***  Type (describe-mode) for help.
ELISP> (let ((some-symbol 0))
         (defconst some-symbol 1412)
         some-symbol)
0 (#o0, #x0, ?\C-@)
ELISP> (let ((some-symbol 0))
         (defconst some-symbol 1412)
         some-symbol)
1412 (#o2604, #x584)
ELISP>
```

---

emacs-version: 28.2
system-configuration: x86_64-w64-mingw32

Comment: Indeed, it behaves the same on Emacs 30. Although `defconst` does work as documented when using it with `let`: `(let ((some-symbol 0)) (defconst some-symbol 1412) some-symbol)` returns 1412. Then again `defvar` does not work as documented when using it with `let`. To me it looks like you've encountered a 'documentation bug'.

Comment: I am on Emacs 28.2 on Linux, works fine for me. I get 1412 from `f` and error on evaluating `some-symbol`. Same with `let`.

Comment: @dalanicolai: Thanks for your example. I will add it to my question description, because the first time my Emacs evaluates it, the result is `0`!

Comment: The `defvar` doc in the upstream repo says: `If SYMBOL is let-bound, then this form does not affect the local let
binding but the toplevel default binding instead, like
‘set-toplevel-default-binding‘.
(‘defcustom’ behaves similarly in this respect.)`. I think it is likely that some of these behaviors might be "fluid", as bugs are found and fixed. I suspect that they will be cleaned up as time goes on, but you should probably report  what you find perplexing, particularly if it contradicts the documentation.

Comment: @Arktik Probably you did not activate the [lexical-binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html). To get lexical binding in \*scratch\*, be sure to use `lisp-interaction-mode` (the default for vanilla Emacs, but not on e.g. Spacemacs) and NOT `emacs-lisp-mode`. Of course, anyway thanks for the feedback...